# PHP: counting all the items of a multilevel array containing a given parameter and a given value

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to build a function to count all the items of an array containing a given parameter, but, if the parameter is not given when calling the function, the function should count all the items. Parameters are passed with an array `$params`: This is what I have done so far:

```
function myfunction($params){
  global $myArray;

  if ( !isset($params[0]) ){ $params[0] = ???????? } // I need a wildcard here, so that, if the parameter is not given, the condition will be true by default
  if ( !isset($params[1]) ){ $params[1] = ???????? } // I need a wildcard here, so that, if the parameter is not given, the condition will be true by default
  ....etc......

  foreach($myArray as $item){
     if ($item[0] == $params[0]){ // this condition should be true if parameter is not given
         if ($item[1] == $params[1]){// this condition should be true if parameter is not given

             $count += $item
         }
     }
  }

  return $count;
}
```

I would like:

```
myfunction(); //counts everything
myfunction( array ('0' => 'banana') ); //counts only $myArray['0'] = banana
myfunction( array ('0' => 'apple', '1' => 'eggs') ); //counts only $myArray['0'] = apples and $myArray['1'] = eggs
```

I have several $params[keys] to check this way.

I guess, if I should assign a default value to `params[key]` (like a wildcard) , so that, if it is not given, the function will take all the $item. I mean something that `$item[0]` will always be (==) equal to. Thanks. [See my answer for solution]

Comment: Read about the `else` that goes along with `if`

Comment: If you want to set default values, why not create an array of default values and use `array_merge()` with your incoming `$params` array?

Comment: Not understandable question!

Comment: @alzee Thanks, but I don't know how. Could you show me how to implement the `else` im my function to let it count all the items if `$params[0]` is not given?

Comment: @Terry `array_merge()` probably won't give the desired results:  From the [array_merge man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), "If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the `+` array union operator" - the function input parameters are the first (left) array, the defaults the second (right) array in this case.

Comment: @Jerald Hi, just edited my question. Hope is better. Do you think you can give me an hand? Thanks

Comment: After your edit, I'm more confused - what is the "everything" that's supposed to be counted when you don't pass a parameter?

Comment: @FKEinternet I mean in the `if statement`, if the parameter is not given, by default the condition should always be true (and consequentially do the count).

Comment: I'm counting how many items I have in `$myArray`. If the parameter is given, count only where `$myArray` contains the parameter. If the parameter is not given, count everything

Comment: A var dump of $myArray would be useful. Is it a bi-dimensional array with string-integer indexes?

Comment: @Sal, yes bidimensional with string indexes

Answer (score 2):

The way your function is declared, you *have* to pass a parameter.  What you want to do is have a default value so that your code inside the function can detect that:

```
function myfunction($params=NULL)
{
    global $myArray;

    if (empty($params))
    {
        // count everything
    }
    else
    {
        // count what's listed in the $params array
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

If I read your comments correctly, `$myArray` looks something like this:

```
$myArray=array
(
    'apple'=>3,     // 3 apples
    'orange'=>4,    // 4 oranges
    'banana'=>2,    // 2 bananas
    'eggs'=>12,     // 12 eggs
    'coconut'=>1,   // 1 coconut
);
```

Assuming that's true, what you want is

```
function myfunction($params=NULL)
{
    global $myArray;
    $count=0;

    if (empty($params))    // count everything
    {
        foreach ($myArray as $num)  // keys are ignored
            $count += $num;
    }
    else if (!is_array($params))    // sanity check
    {
        // display an error, write to error_log(), etc. as appropriate
    }
    else    // count what's listed in the $params array
    {
        foreach ($params as $key)  // check each item listed in $params
            if (isset($myArray[$key]))    // insure request in $myArray
                $count += $myArray[$key];    // add item's count to total
    }

    return $count;
}
```

This will give you

```
myfunction();                          // returns 22
myfunction(array('banana'));           // returns 2
myfunction(array('apple','eggs'));     // returns 15
myfunction(array('tomatoes'));         // returns 0 - not in $myArray
```

If this isn't the result you're looking for, you need to rewrite your question.

**EDIT # 2**

Note that because arrays specified without explicit keys are keyed numerically in the order the elements are listed, the function calls I showed above are exactly equivalent to these:

```
myfunction();                              // returns 22
myfunction(array(0=>'banana'));            // returns 2
myfunction(array(0=>'apple',1=>'eggs'));   // returns 15
myfunction(array(0=>'tomatoes'));          // returns 0 - not in $myArray
```

However, the calls are **not** equivalent to these:

```
myfunction();                                  // returns 22
myfunction(array('0'=>'banana'));              // returns 2
myfunction(array('0'=>'apple','1'=>'eggs'));   // returns 15
myfunction(array('0'=>'tomatoes'));            // returns 0
```

In this case, *explicit **string** keys* are specified for the array, and while the strings' values will evaluate the same as the numerical indices *under **most** circumstances*, string indices are *not* the same as numerical ones.

The code you proposed in your answer has a few errors:

```
foreach($myArray as $item)
{
    foreach ($params as $key => $value)
    {
        if ( isset($params[$key]) && $params[$key] == $item[$key]  )
        {
            $count += $item
        }
    }
}
```

First, `isset($params[$key])` will ***always*** evaluate to **TRUE** by the nature or arrays and `foreach`.  Second, because of your outer `foreach` loop, if your `$myArray` is structured as I illustrated above, calling `myfunction(array('apple'))` will result in `$params[$key] == $item[$key]` making these tests because `$key` is `0`:

```
'apple' == 'apple'[0]    // testing 'apple' == 'a'
'apple' == 'orange'[0]   // testing 'apple' == 'o'
'apple' == 'banana'[0]   // testing 'apple' == 'b'
'apple' == 'eggs'[0]     // testing 'apple' == 'e'
'apple' == 'coconut'[0]  // testing 'apple' == 'c'
```

As you can see, this will not produce the expected results.

The third problem with your code is you don't have a semicolon at the end of the `$count += $item` line, so I'm guessing you didn't try running this code before proposing it as an answer.

**EDIT # 3**

Since your original question isn't terribly clear, it occurred to me that maybe what you're trying to do is count the number of *types* of things in `$myArray` rather than to get a total of the number of items in each requested category.  In that case, the last branch of `myfunction()` is even simpler:

```
    else    // count what's listed in the $params array
    {
        foreach ($params as $key)  // check each item listed in $params
            if (isset($myArray[$key]))    // insure request in $myArray
                $count++;    // add the item to the total
    }
```

With the sample `$myArray` I illustrated, the above change will give you

```
myfunction();                          // returns 5
myfunction(array('banana'));           // returns 1
myfunction(array('apple','eggs'));     // returns 2
myfunction(array('tomatoes'));         // returns 0 - not in $myArray
```

Again, if neither of these results are what you're looking for, you need to rewrite your question and ***include a sample of `$myArray`***.

Comment: Thanks FKE. I came out with a solution that works for me. I like yours, but I don't know how to count in the else statement when you have nested if-else, like in my case. Could you show it in your solution, please?

Comment: What does your $myArray look like? Are the nested if-else really necessary?

Comment: BTW, asking for an update of an answer, then going away without looking at it could be considered impolite - what was the point in asking me to *spend my time* to flesh out my answer if you weren't going to see what it was?

Comment: sorry I did not mean to be impolite or abuse of your time... but sometimes I need to go to work to pay my bills... ;) I'm sure you will understand. I'm back now I'll look into it and I will keep you posted and for sure up vote your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Please do let me know if my interpretation of your problem was correct, and whether or not my code helped.

Comment: Almost there! ;) I proposed a new answer because your answer (which was veery useful) check if the array has a key that corresponds to the params values, but I need to compare keys and values. I upvoted your answer because it really put me in the right direction.  PS. If you don't mind and if you think it's right, could upvote my answer, I don't know why it shows a -1, it seems fair  aswer to me... :( Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**MY SOLUTION**

(Not extensively tested, but works so far)

Following @FKEinternet answer, this is the solution that works for me: obviously the $params should use the same keys of $item. So, foreach iteration if parameter['mykey'] is given when calling the function and its value is equal to item['mykey'], count the iteration and $count grows of +1

```
function myfunction($params=NULL){
  global $myArray;

  foreach($myArray as $item){
     foreach ($params as $key => $value){
          if ( isset($params[$key]) && $params[$key] == $item[$key]  ){ 
             $count += $item;
         }
     }
  }

  return $count;
}
```

Thanks everybody for all inputs!!

Comment: Did you try running this code before proposing it as an answer?  (See my Edit #2 for why I don't think you did.)  You should try actually running my code before discounting it - unless your `$myArray` is *not* structured the way I illustrated it, my code *will* give you the desired results.  If your `$myArray` is *not* structured that way, *edit your question* to *include an illustration of the correct `$myArray` structure*.